# How can I pretty-print ASCII tables with Python?

Tags: python, ascii, tabular

I'm looking for a way to pretty-print tables like this:

```
=======================
| column 1 | column 2 |
=======================
| value1   | value2   |
| value3   | value4   |
=======================
```

I've found the [asciitable](http://cxc.harvard.edu/contrib/asciitable/) library but it doesn't do the borders, etc. I don't need any complex formatting of data items, they're just strings. I do need it to auto-size columns.

Do other libraries or methods exist, or do I need to spend a few minutes writing my own?

Comment: Why not use docutils to do this for you?

Comment: What do you call a table ? How is the data organised in a table ? Are value1, value2, value3, value4... the successive values in a list ? I think that fomat() is enough to obtain such a simple display, no need to learn during a long time a tutorial that explains how to gain time by using a library

Comment: @korona: No, I wasn't making a suggestion.  I was asking a question.  I have no clue what @kdt knows or doesn't know.  Rather than assume, I feel compelled to ask.

Comment: Sounded to me like you were in fact assuming that he knows about docutils. Maybe he doesn't?

Comment: @S.Lott I've looked at docutils, and while it is of course great for converting text to html, latex, etc, I don't see a way to *generate* nice text tables, with columns that line up and look pretty with fixed-width fonts.  Did you misunderstand kdt's goal, or am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing tabular data in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122347/printing-tabular-data-in-python)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For some reason when I included 'docutils' in my google searches I stumbled across [texttable](https://pypi.org/project/texttable/), which seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Nice one. Lacks automatic column width detection; use: http://pastebin.com/SAsPJUxM

Answer (score 99):

I've read this question long time ago, and finished writing my own pretty-printer for tables: [`tabulate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate).

My use case is:

- I want a one-liner most of the time
- which is smart enough to figure the best formatting for me
- and can output different plain-text formats

Given your example, `grid` is probably the most similar output format:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print tabulate([["value1", "value2"], ["value3", "value4"]], ["column 1", "column 2"], tablefmt="grid")
+------------+------------+
| column 1   | column 2   |
+============+============+
| value1     | value2     |
+------------+------------+
| value3     | value4     |
+------------+------------+
```

Other supported formats are `plain` (no lines), `simple` (Pandoc simple tables), `pipe` (like tables in PHP Markdown Extra), `orgtbl` (like tables in Emacs' org-mode), `rst` (like simple tables in reStructuredText). `grid` and `orgtbl` are easily editable in Emacs.

Performance-wise, `tabulate` is slightly slower than `asciitable`, but much faster than `PrettyTable` and `texttable`.

P.S. I'm also a big fan of aligning numbers [by a decimal column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/aligning-numbers-by-decimal-points-in-table-columns). So this is the default alignment for numbers if there are any (overridable).

Comment: I just happened to need a tabulating solution and was fortunate enough to find your library! Works like a charm :D

In case you're listening, just wanted to say **Thank You** :)

Comment: Yes, I'm listening. Thank you for the kind words. It's really nice to get positive feedback.

Comment: Hi, @sastanin First of all, thank you very much for such a nice library. May I know is there any option to print table to span whole width of terminal?

Comment: Hello sastanin, just wanted to drop a word here to thank you for this very handy package. Works like a charm and saved me the trouble of writing my own. Thanks a lot for sharing !

Comment: Your feature list is  an understatement. Tried ansi escaped stuff, works perfect. Thanks for this!

Comment: [`pandas` 1.0.0 or higher can print a dataframe in markdown format directly](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#converting-to-markdown) with the help of `tabulate`. It's handy when data can be managed in `pandas` dataframe and get printed directly.

Answer (score 40):

Here's a quick and dirty little function I wrote for displaying the results from SQL queries I can only make over a SOAP API. It expects an input of a sequence of one or more `namedtuples` as table rows. If there's only one record, it prints it out differently.

It is handy for me and could be a starting point for you:

```
def pprinttable(rows):
  if len(rows) > 1:
    headers = rows[0]._fields
    lens = []
    for i in range(len(rows[0])):
      lens.append(len(max([x[i] for x in rows] + [headers[i]],key=lambda x:len(str(x)))))
    formats = []
    hformats = []
    for i in range(len(rows[0])):
      if isinstance(rows[0][i], int):
        formats.append("%%%dd" % lens[i])
      else:
        formats.append("%%-%ds" % lens[i])
      hformats.append("%%-%ds" % lens[i])
    pattern = " | ".join(formats)
    hpattern = " | ".join(hformats)
    separator = "-+-".join(['-' * n for n in lens])
    print hpattern % tuple(headers)
    print separator
    _u = lambda t: t.decode('UTF-8', 'replace') if isinstance(t, str) else t
    for line in rows:
        print pattern % tuple(_u(t) for t in line)
  elif len(rows) == 1:
    row = rows[0]
    hwidth = len(max(row._fields,key=lambda x: len(x)))
    for i in range(len(row)):
      print "%*s = %s" % (hwidth,row._fields[i],row[i])
```

Sample output:

```
pkid                                 | fkn                                  | npi
-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----
405fd665-0a2f-4f69-7320-be01201752ec | 8c9949b9-552e-e448-64e2-74292834c73e | 0
5b517507-2a42-ad2e-98dc-8c9ac6152afa | f972bee7-f5a4-8532-c4e5-2e82897b10f6 | 0
2f960dfc-b67a-26be-d1b3-9b105535e0a8 | ec3e1058-8840-c9f2-3b25-2488f8b3a8af | 1
c71b28a3-5299-7f4d-f27a-7ad8aeadafe0 | 72d25703-4735-310b-2e06-ff76af1e45ed | 0
3b0a5021-a52b-9ba0-1439-d5aafcf348e7 | d81bb78a-d984-e957-034d-87434acb4e97 | 1
96c36bb7-c4f4-2787-ada8-4aadc17d1123 | c171fe85-33e2-6481-0791-2922267e8777 | 1
95d0f85f-71da-bb9a-2d80-fe27f7c02fe2 | 226f964c-028d-d6de-bf6c-688d2908c5ae | 1
132aa774-42e5-3d3f-498b-50b44a89d401 | 44e31f89-d089-8afc-f4b1-ada051c01474 | 1
ff91641a-5802-be02-bece-79bca993fdbc | 33d8294a-053d-6ab4-94d4-890b47fcf70d | 1
f3196e15-5b61-e92d-e717-f00ed93fe8ae | 62fa4566-5ca2-4a36-f872-4d00f7abadcf | 1
```

---

Example

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Row = namedtuple('Row',['first','second','third'])
>>> data = Row(1,2,3)
>>> data
Row(first=1, second=2, third=3)
>>> pprinttable([data])
 first = 1
second = 2
 third = 3
>>> pprinttable([data,data])
first | second | third
------+--------+------
    1 |      2 |     3
    1 |      2 |     3
```

Comment: @MattH can you show the usage of this function with an example?

Comment: @MattH thanks, but big number seems to crash it right away. TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len().

Comment: @Alborz: I posted this as a starting point for others, customise it to deal with your data types if you want to. Though depending on which line that error came from, you might not be calling the function as intended

Comment: @theAlse I fixed the bug you identified, by making it `len(str(max(...)))` in the lens.append line.  So now if a number in a column is wider than the column header, we're still good.  BTW, MattH - cute use of the "key" argument to max()!

Answer (score 14):

I too wrote my own solution to this. I tried to keep it simple.

https://github.com/Robpol86/terminaltables

```
from terminaltables import AsciiTable
table_data = [
    ['Heading1', 'Heading2'],
    ['row1 column1', 'row1 column2'],
    ['row2 column1', 'row2 column2']
]
table = AsciiTable(table_data)
print table.table
+--------------+--------------+
| Heading1     | Heading2     |
+--------------+--------------+
| row1 column1 | row1 column2 |
| row2 column1 | row2 column2 |
+--------------+--------------+

table.inner_heading_row_border = False
print table.table
+--------------+--------------+
| Heading1     | Heading2     |
| row1 column1 | row1 column2 |
| row2 column1 | row2 column2 |
+--------------+--------------+

table.inner_row_border = True
table.justify_columns[1] = 'right'
table.table_data[1][1] += '\nnewline'
print table.table
+--------------+--------------+
| Heading1     |     Heading2 |
+--------------+--------------+
| row1 column1 | row1 column2 |
|              |      newline |
+--------------+--------------+
| row2 column1 | row2 column2 |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: This project seems dead

Answer (score 13):

I just released [termtables](https://github.com/nschloe/termtables) for this purpose. For example, this

```py
import termtables as tt

tt.print(
    [[1, 2, 3], [613.23236243236, 613.23236243236, 613.23236243236]],
    header=["a", "bb", "ccc"],
    style=tt.styles.ascii_thin_double,
    padding=(0, 1),
    alignment="lcr"
)
```

gets you

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| a               |       bb        |             ccc |
+=================+=================+=================+
| 1               |        2        |               3 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 613.23236243236 | 613.23236243236 | 613.23236243236 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

By default, the table is rendered with Unicode [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character),

```
┌─────────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ a               │       bb        │             ccc │
╞═════════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1               │        2        │               3 │
├─────────────────┼─────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ 613.23236243236 │ 613.23236243236 │ 613.23236243236 │
└─────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

termtables are very configurable; check out [the tests](https://github.com/nschloe/termtables/blob/master/test/test_termtables.py) for more examples.

Comment: I wish you could set the maximum column to display and let the library handle the wrapping logic.

Answer (score 8):

If you want a table with column and row spans, then try my library [dashtable](https://github.com/doakey3/DashTable)

```
from dashtable import data2rst

table = [
        ["Header 1", "Header 2", "Header3", "Header 4"],
        ["row 1", "column 2", "column 3", "column 4"],
        ["row 2", "Cells span columns.", "", ""],
        ["row 3", "Cells\nspan rows.", "- Cells\n- contain\n- blocks", ""],
        ["row 4", "", "", ""]
    ]

# [Row, Column] pairs of merged cells
span0 = ([2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3])
span1 = ([3, 1], [4, 1])
span2 = ([3, 3], [3, 2], [4, 2], [4, 3])

my_spans = [span0, span1, span2]

print(data2rst(table, spans=my_spans, use_headers=True))
```

Which outputs:

```
+----------+------------+----------+----------+
| Header 1 | Header 2   | Header3  | Header 4 |
+==========+============+==========+==========+
| row 1    | column 2   | column 3 | column 4 |
+----------+------------+----------+----------+
| row 2    | Cells span columns.              |
+----------+----------------------------------+
| row 3    | Cells      | - Cells             |
+----------+ span rows. | - contain           |
| row 4    |            | - blocks            |
+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: `ERROR: Spans must be a list of lists`

Answer (score 7):

Version using w3m designed to handle the types MattH's version accepts:

```
import subprocess
import tempfile
import html
def pprinttable(rows):
    esc = lambda x: html.escape(str(x))
    sour = "<table border=1>"
    if len(rows) == 1:
        for i in range(len(rows[0]._fields)):
            sour += "<tr><th>%s<td>%s" % (esc(rows[0]._fields[i]), esc(rows[0][i]))
    else:
        sour += "<tr>" + "".join(["<th>%s" % esc(x) for x in rows[0]._fields])
        sour += "".join(["<tr>%s" % "".join(["<td>%s" % esc(y) for y in x]) for x in rows])
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".html") as f:
        f.write(sour.encode("utf-8"))
        f.flush()
        print(
            subprocess
            .Popen(["w3m","-dump",f.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            .communicate()[0].decode("utf-8").strip()
        )

from collections import namedtuple
Row = namedtuple('Row',['first','second','third'])
data1 = Row(1,2,3)
data2 = Row(4,5,6)
pprinttable([data1])
pprinttable([data1,data2])
```

results in:

```
┌───────┬─┐
│ first │1│
├───────┼─┤
│second │2│
├───────┼─┤
│ third │3│
└───────┴─┘
┌─────┬───────┬─────┐
│first│second │third│
├─────┼───────┼─────┤
│1    │2      │3    │
├─────┼───────┼─────┤
│4    │5      │6    │
└─────┴───────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try [BeautifulTable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifultable). It does what you want to do. Here's an example from it's [documentation](http://beautifultable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
>>> from beautifultable import BeautifulTable
>>> table = BeautifulTable()
>>> table.columns.header = ["name", "rank", "gender"]
>>> table.rows.append(["Jacob", 1, "boy"])
>>> table.rows.append(["Isabella", 1, "girl"])
>>> table.rows.append(["Ethan", 2, "boy"])
>>> table.rows.append(["Sophia", 2, "girl"])
>>> table.rows.append(["Michael", 3, "boy"])
>>> print(table)
+----------+------+--------+
|   name   | rank | gender |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Jacob   |  1   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
| Isabella |  1   |  girl  |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Ethan   |  2   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Sophia  |  2   |  girl  |
+----------+------+--------+
| Michael  |  3   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
```

Comment: ```/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/beautifultable/utils.py:113: FutureWarning: 'BeautifulTable.column_headers' has been deprecated in 'v1.0.0' and will be removed in 'v1.2.0'. Use 'BTColumnCollection.header' instead.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)```

Answer (score 3):

```
from sys import stderr, stdout    
def create_table(table: dict, full_row: bool = False) -> None:

        min_len = len(min((v for v in table.values()), key=lambda q: len(q)))
        max_len = len(max((v for v in table.values()), key=lambda q: len(q)))

        if min_len < max_len:
            stderr.write("Table is out of shape, please make sure all columns have the same length.")
            stderr.flush()
            return

        additional_spacing = 1

        heading_separator = '| '
        horizontal_split = '| '

        rc_separator = ''
        key_list = list(table.keys())
        rc_len_values = []
        for key in key_list:
            rc_len = len(max((v for v in table[key]), key=lambda q: len(str(q))))
            rc_len_values += ([rc_len, [key]] for n in range(len(table[key])))

            heading_line = (key + (" " * (rc_len + (additional_spacing + 1)))) + heading_separator
            stdout.write(heading_line)

            rc_separator += ("-" * (len(key) + (rc_len + (additional_spacing + 1)))) + '+-'

            if key is key_list[-1]:
                stdout.flush()
                stdout.write('\n' + rc_separator + '\n')

        value_list = [v for vl in table.values() for v in vl]

        aligned_data_offset = max_len

        row_count = len(key_list)

        next_idx = 0
        newline_indicator = 0
        iterations = 0

        for n in range(len(value_list)):
            key = rc_len_values[next_idx][1][0]
            rc_len = rc_len_values[next_idx][0]

            line = ('{:{}} ' + " " * len(key)).format(value_list[next_idx], str(rc_len + additional_spacing)) + horizontal_split

            if next_idx >= (len(value_list) - aligned_data_offset):
                next_idx = iterations + 1
                iterations += 1
            else:
                next_idx += aligned_data_offset

            if newline_indicator >= row_count:
                if full_row:
                    stdout.flush()
                    stdout.write('\n' + rc_separator + '\n')
                else:
                    stdout.flush()
                    stdout.write('\n')

                newline_indicator = 0

            stdout.write(line)
            newline_indicator += 1

        stdout.write('\n' + rc_separator + '\n')
        stdout.flush()
```

Example:

```
table = {
        "uid": ["0", "1", "2", "3"],
        "name": ["Jon", "Doe", "Lemma", "Hemma"]
    }

create_table(table)
```

Output:

```
uid   | name       | 
------+------------+-
0     | Jon        | 
1     | Doe        | 
2     | Lemma      | 
3     | Hemma      | 
------+------------+-
```

Comment: You could improve your code-only answer by augmenting it with some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I know it the question is a bit old but here's my attempt at this:

https://gist.github.com/lonetwin/4721748

It is a bit more readable IMHO (although it doesn't differentiate between single / multiple rows like @MattH's solutions does, nor does it use NamedTuples).

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```
def make_table(columns, data):
    """Create an ASCII table and return it as a string.

    Pass a list of strings to use as columns in the table and a list of
    dicts. The strings in 'columns' will be used as the keys to the dicts in
    'data.'

    Not all column values have to be present in each data dict.

    >>> print(make_table(["a", "b"], [{"a": "1", "b": "test"}]))
    | a | b    |
    |----------|
    | 1 | test |
    """
    # Calculate how wide each cell needs to be
    cell_widths = {}
    for c in columns:
        values = [str(d.get(c, "")) for d in data]
        cell_widths[c] = len(max(values + [c]))

    # Used for formatting rows of data
    row_template = "|" + " {} |" * len(columns)

    # CONSTRUCT THE TABLE

    # The top row with the column titles
    justified_column_heads = [c.ljust(cell_widths[c]) for c in columns]
    header = row_template.format(*justified_column_heads)
    # The second row contains separators
    sep = "|" + "-" * (len(header) - 2) + "|"
    # Rows of data
    rows = []
    for d in data:
        fields = [str(d.get(c, "")).ljust(cell_widths[c]) for c in columns]
        row = row_template.format(*fields)
        rows.append(row)

    return "\n".join([header, sep] + rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this small utility function.

```
def get_pretty_table(iterable, header):
    max_len = [len(x) for x in header]
    for row in iterable:
        row = [row] if type(row) not in (list, tuple) else row
        for index, col in enumerate(row):
            if max_len[index] < len(str(col)):
                max_len[index] = len(str(col))
    output = '-' * (sum(max_len) + 1) + '\n'
    output += '|' + ''.join([h + ' ' * (l - len(h)) + '|' for h, l in zip(header, max_len)]) + '\n'
    output += '-' * (sum(max_len) + 1) + '\n'
    for row in iterable:
        row = [row] if type(row) not in (list, tuple) else row
        output += '|' + ''.join([str(c) + ' ' * (l - len(str(c))) + '|' for c, l in zip(row, max_len)]) + '\n'
    output += '-' * (sum(max_len) + 1) + '\n'
    return output

print get_pretty_table([[1, 2], [3, 4]], ['header 1', 'header 2'])
```

output

```
-----------------
|header 1|header 2|
-----------------
|1       |2       |
|3       |4       |
-----------------
```

Comment: You're adding a space between each column in 

`output += '|' + ''.join([h + ' ' * (l - len(h)) + '|' for h, l in zip(header, max_len)]) + '\n'`

but not in the separator lines.

Can extend that row of `-`s with something as simple as

`output = '-' * (sum(max_len) + 1 + len(header)) + '\n'`

Comment: Should be called `get_shitty_table()`

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with only builtin modules fairly compactly using list and string comprehensions.  Accepts a list of dictionaries all of the same format...

```
def tableit(dictlist):
    lengths = [ max(map(lambda x:len(x.get(k)), dictlist) + [len(k)]) for k in dictlist[0].keys() ]
    lenstr = " | ".join("{:<%s}" % m for m in lengths)
    lenstr += "\n"

    outmsg = lenstr.format(*dictlist[0].keys())
    outmsg += "-" * (sum(lengths) + 3*len(lengths))
    outmsg += "\n"
    outmsg += "".join(
        lenstr.format(*v) for v in [ item.values() for item in dictlist ]
    )
    return outmsg
```

Comment: Please submit a example how to use your code. `tableit([dict(a='1', b='2', c='3'), dict(a='x', b='y', c='z')])`

Comment: You code does not work without changes in python 3, line 2 must be: `lengths = [ max(list(map(lambda x:len(x.get(k)), dictlist)) + [len(k)]) for k in dictlist[0].keys() ]`