# Printing lists onto tables in python

Tags: python, list

If i had three lists such as

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]
```

And wanted to print it like this

```
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

How would i do that?

Comment: meaby duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214809/pretty-print-2d-python-list, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712085/numpy-pretty-print-tabular-data, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909873/python-pretty-printing-ascii-tables

Answer (score 8):

The hard part of this is transposing the array. But that's easy, with [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]
t = zip(a, b, c)
```

Now you just print it out:

```
print('\n'.join('  '.join(map(str, row)) for row in t))
```

Comment: IMHO, a very readable solution. I like keeping the zip separate (unlike other answers) because transposing and displaying are fundamentally different things to do.

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
'\n'.join(' '.join(map(str,tup)) for tup in zip(a,b,c))
```

Comment: +1, if for no other reason than you answered this in 36 seconds.

Comment: I think you want `'  '`, because the OP has two spaces between columns. Or leave it as `' '` and do `str(x).ljust(2)` instead of `str`.

Comment: Hold on, this is wrong… the OP is trying to print the lists transposed.

Comment: This does not give output that OP asked for.

Comment: @abarnert -- Thanks.  I didn't notice that until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

With <del>list comprehension</del> generator expression, without the map function:

```
'\n'.join(' '.join(str(y) for y in x) for x in zip(a,b,c))
```

Comment: First, in cases where all you're doing is mapping a nicely-named function that you already have lying around, why not use `map`? Yeah, it's less readable when you have to build a `lambda` or a `partial`, but in this case, I think it's _more_ readable. (Also, you don't have a list comprehension here, you have a generator expression.)

Comment: @abarnert: you just answered your question yourself: map unnecessarily creates a list, which is not created because I use a generator expression (sorry for the faulty naming, edited that). A generator is cleaner than a list. I should also use the functional equivalent of zip, so add `from itertools import izip as zip` to the top of the script.

Comment: @pvoosten: Actually, `join` creates a list when you give it an iterator (at least with CPython and PyPy, probably with all implementations). Also, `map` doesn't create a list in 3.x. Most importantly, the performance implications of creating a list of 3 elements are so negligible that even having this discussion is silly. Use whichever one is more readable.