# how to create the special table to wrap my data in python?

Tags: python

Here is my data.

```
['date', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5']  
['2014-02-26', '302964.13', '11715.30', '1389.87', '404.63', '304354.00']  
['2014-02-25', '297672.69', '7406.57', '1733.45', '345.70', '299406.14']  
['2014-02-24', '297957.19', '9933.49', '1514.91', '345.56', '299472.10']  
['2014-02-21', '312826.51', '9365.13', '1308.66', '266.03', '314135.17']   
['2014-02-20', '325884.05', '10152.87', '1576.65', '483.17', '327460.70']  
['2014-02-19', '330013.56', '17205.76', '1729.29', '709.73', '331742.85']  
['2014-02-18', '327645.32', '11282.95', '1359.65', '190.63', '329004.96']  
['2014-02-17', '324224.52', '13298.12', '1080.77', '145.35', '325305.29']  
['2014-02-14', '324022.62', '11353.54', '1254.47', '183.25', '325277.08']  
['2014-02-13', '330918.46', '25570.06', '1597.78', '695.83', '332516.24']  
['2014-02-12', '324835.65', '10588.67', '1630.50', '456.97', '326466.15']  
['2014-02-11', '325785.09', '23822.77', '2214.77', '599.14', '327999.86']  
['2014-02-10', '319886.55', '12657.06', '1759.45', '169.27', '321646.00']  
['2014-02-07', '312989.44', '11284.82', '2225.87', '165.09', '315215.31']  
['2014-01-30', '305685.92', '3278.42', '1441.53', '65.08', '307127.45']  
['2014-01-29', '310027.36', '4866.76', '1211.53', '171.60', '311238.89']  
['2014-01-28', '311252.25', '5307.47', '1627.93', '110.17', '312880.19']  
['2014-01-27', '313464.93', '5316.03', '1579.17', '170.52', '315044.10']  
['2014-01-24', '315828.12', '9967.38', '1614.39', '222.52', '317442.51']
```

I want to wrap it into the form.

[image]

I can create the head and body

Head:

```
｜ date     ｜     x1   ｜  x2      ｜  x3    ｜    x4    ｜  x5        ｜
```

body:

```
｜2014-02-27｜ 303664.88｜   9753.48｜ 1455.21｜    483.72｜   305120.10｜
｜2014-02-26｜ 302964.13｜  11715.30｜ 1389.87｜    404.63｜   304354.00｜
｜2014-02-25｜ 297672.69｜   7406.57｜ 1733.45｜    345.70｜   299406.14｜
｜2014-02-24｜ 297957.19｜   9933.49｜ 1514.91｜    345.56｜   299472.10｜
｜2014-02-21｜ 312826.51｜   9365.13｜ 1308.66｜    266.03｜   314135.17｜
｜2014-02-20｜ 325884.05｜  10152.87｜ 1576.65｜    483.17｜   327460.70｜
｜2014-02-19｜ 330013.56｜  17205.76｜ 1729.29｜    709.73｜   331742.85｜
｜2014-02-18｜ 327645.32｜  11282.95｜ 1359.65｜    190.63｜   329004.96｜
｜2014-02-17｜ 324224.52｜  13298.12｜ 1080.77｜    145.35｜   325305.29｜
｜2014-02-14｜ 324022.62｜  11353.54｜ 1254.47｜    183.25｜   325277.08｜
｜2014-02-13｜ 330918.46｜  25570.06｜ 1597.78｜    695.83｜   332516.24｜
｜2014-02-12｜ 324835.65｜  10588.67｜ 1630.50｜    456.97｜   326466.15｜
｜2014-02-11｜ 325785.09｜  23822.77｜ 2214.77｜    599.14｜   327999.86｜
｜2014-02-10｜ 319886.55｜  12657.06｜ 1759.45｜    169.27｜   321646.00｜
｜2014-02-07｜ 312989.44｜  11284.82｜ 2225.87｜    165.09｜   315215.31｜
｜2014-01-30｜ 305685.92｜   3278.42｜ 1441.53｜     65.08｜   307127.45｜
｜2014-01-29｜ 310027.36｜   4866.76｜ 1211.53｜    171.60｜   311238.89｜
｜2014-01-28｜ 311252.25｜   5307.47｜ 1627.93｜    110.17｜   312880.19｜
｜2014-01-27｜ 313464.93｜   5316.03｜ 1579.17｜    170.52｜   315044.10｜
｜2014-01-24｜ 315828.12｜   9967.38｜ 1614.39｜    222.52｜   317442.51｜
```

how to create the first line in the table?

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────┬─────┬──────┐
```

and the third line in the table?

```
├─────┼─────┼─────┼────┼─────┼──────┤
```

and the last line in the table?

```
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────┴─────┴──────┘
```

please write it in python.

the form is :

```
+------------+---------+-------------+
| column_one | col_two |   column_3  |
+------------+---------+-------------+
|          0 |  0.0001 | ABCD        |
|          1 |  1e-005 | ABCD        |
|          2 |  1e-006 | long string |
|          3 |  1e-007 | ABCD        |
+------------+---------+-------------+
```

not absolutely the same as mine posted here.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712085/numpy-pretty-print-tabular-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How obout taking the `prettytable` output (suggested in comment to your post) and just replacing the `+` chars with ones from your example? Pretty simple thing.