# Human readable alternative to CSV

Tags: csv, tabular

Are there any formats for tables that are more readable than CSV and have good programming language support?

I need to store some financial information in Git for auditing, and I want commit diffs to be readable so that I can review them from email. I don't expect strings to exceed 20 characters, so the format that is good for tables with fixed size columns is fine.

**UPDATE**: I like the idea mentioned in [NumPy: Pretty print tabular data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712085/numpy-pretty-print-tabular-data) If that format has a name and parser/generator support, that would be a good answer to my problem.

```
 column_one | col_two |  column_3
------------+---------+-------------
          0 |  0.0001 | ABCD
          1 |  1e-005 | long string
          2 |  1e-008 | ABCD
          3 |  1e-007 | ABCD
```

Comment: Plain text? (I.e., convert commas to tabs and expand the tabs.)

Comment: @Jongware, yes, plain text that can be parsed with existing libraries.

Comment: Well, "plain text" was meant as my suggestion, not a question. The Having to Parse afterwards may be a problem then, as spaced out plain text is notoriously hard to handle. Tab-separated would be my second choice, then, although it still won't be *very* readable if some strings are significantly longer than others.

Comment: @Jongware, I've updated the question. Is there some format that looks like this?