# Check for uniformity of a multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

Following my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126305/pretty-printing-numpy-ndarrays-using-unicode-charachters) I was surprised to know that Numpy is pretty loose on the definition of array_like objects. Basically `np.array(1)` is a valid numpy ndarray of shape `()` and dimension of `0`! also `np.array([[1,2],[3]])` is a valid ndarray of shape `(2,)` and dimension of `1`. Basically `np.array` digs as many dimensions as possible till it reaches nonuniformity or zero-dimensional values. This implementation might be pretty fast, but is not necessarily safe. In fact it is very error prone. if somebody forgets one element of an input list, the function returns no error, leading to other most probably more confusing errors down the code.

I was thinking if it is possible to write a checkArr function to check the homogeneity and uniformity of the multidimensional list, with the least possible overhead. Scavenging over a couple of other SO post I ended up with this recursive solution:

```
def checkArr(A):
    assert isinstance(A, (list,tuple,range)), 
             "input must be iterable (list, tuple, range)"
    assert all(isinstance(a, type(A[0])) for a in A[1:]), 
             "elements of the input must of a the same type, input must be homogeneous"
    if isinstance(A[0], (list,tuple,range)):
        assert all(len(a)==len(A[0]) for a in A[1:]),
             "elements of the input must of a the same size, input must be uniform"
        [checkArr(a) for a in A]
```

now my question is if this is the fastest solution or more performant/Pythonic implementations are possible?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying [`dtype` argument](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) when creating an array avoids the unintentional creation of object arrays from jagged matrices, without writing any additional code.

```
np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=int)  # okay
np.array([[1, 2], [3]], dtype=int)     # ValueError
np.array([[1, "b"]], dtype=int)        # ValueError
```

(Regarding the last one, `np.array([1, "b"])` would silently convert "1" to a string if the data type was not set.)

Answer (score 1):

There's Python saying that it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission.  So there might be less overhead if you just call `np.array` and then check for `object` dtype.

One other thing that you need to watch out for is when it throws an error.  For example:

```
In [273]: np.array((np.zeros((2,3)), np.ones((2,4))))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-273-70f6273e3371> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array((np.zeros((2,3)), np.ones((2,4))))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (2)
```

If the non-uniformity is in the first dimension, it produces an object dtype array, e.g. `np.array((np.zeros((2,3)), np.ones((1,4))))`.  But when it's at a deeper level it appears to allocate  the result array, and then has problems copying one or more of the component arrays to it.  This is a tricky case to diagnose.

Or consider:

```
In [277]: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,'6']])
Out[277]: 
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['4', '5', '6']], dtype='<U21')
```

The last element in the nested list forces the string dtype.  And if that last element is some other PYthon object, we may be a object dtype:

```
In [279]: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,{}]])
Out[279]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, {}]], dtype=object)
```

But if the object is a list, we get a variant on the broadcasting error:

```
In [280]: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,['6']]])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

But if you do want to check first, `np.stack` might a good model.  With axis=0 it behaves much like `np.array` if given arrays or lists.