# Read pixels from image in python as in Labview

Tags: python, image

I have to integrate my python code in Labview and I am comparing the pixel value of the image in both.
The Labview gives pixel values in U16 and hence I want to see the pixel values of the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXGat.png)same image in python and see if the values are the same.
Can someone please help me with the code for the same?
My image is a png image black and white.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PIL** or **OpenCV** or **wand** or **scikit-image** for that. Here is a **PIL** version:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open image
im = Image.open('dXGat.png')

# Make into Numpy array for ease of access
na = np.array(im)

# Print shape (pixel dimensions) and data type
print(na.shape,na.dtype)    # prints (256, 320) int32

# Print brightest and darkest pixel
print(na.max(), na.min())

# Print top-left pixel
print(na[0,0])              # prints 25817

# WATCH OUT FOR INDEXING - IT IS ROW FIRST
# print first pixel in second row
print(na[1,0])              # prints 24151

# print first 4 columns of first 2 rows
print(na[0:2,0:4])
```

**Output**

```
array([[25817, 32223, 30301, 33504],
       [24151, 22934, 19859, 21460]], dtype=int32)
```

---

If you prefer to use **OpenCV**, change these lines:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open image
im = Image.open('dXGat.png')

# Make into Numpy array for ease of access
na = np.array(im)
```

to this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Open image
na = cv2.imread('dXGat.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

---

If you just want to one-time inspect the pixels, you can just use **ImageMagick** in the Terminal:

```
magick dXGat.png txt: | more
```

**Sample Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 320,256,65535,gray
0,0: (25817)  #64D964D964D9  gray(39.3942%)
1,0: (32223)  #7DDF7DDF7DDF  gray(49.1691%)
2,0: (30301)  #765D765D765D  gray(46.2364%)
3,0: (33504)  #82E082E082E0  gray(51.1238%)
...
...
317,255: (20371)  #4F934F934F93  gray(31.0842%)
318,255: (20307)  #4F534F534F53  gray(30.9865%)
319,255: (20307)  #4F534F534F53  gray(30.9865%)
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your help. How can I get the values in U16.

Comment: If U16 means unsigned 16-bit, just change the type like this `na = np.array(im).astype(np.uint16)`

Comment: Hi, It still doesn't match with the answer we get from Labview

Comment: Your values seem to be scaled by a factor of 64, relative to what **PIL**, **OpenCV** and **ImageMagick** think, so you can use `na = (np.array(im)//64).astype(np.uint16)`

Comment: I needed one more help . After the calculations in my project I want to print the result including all the numbers.

Comment: intensity_image = intensity_image.astype('uint16')
    print(intensity_image)     But with this I dont get all the numbers. How can I print all the pixels in this.

Comment: You could print a table like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47254935/2836621 Or you could save as a CSV like this `np.savetxt("intensity.csv", intensity_image, delimiter=",")` and view with **Excel**.

Comment: Hi I get the following error - Expected 1D or 2D array, got 3D array instead

Comment: You must be using a different image that is either colour (`na.shape` will be `H,W,3`) or has an alpha channel (`na.shape` will be `H,W,2` or `H,W,4`). What is the shape of your array - I provided code in my answer to print it.

Comment: Yes I get (256, 320, 3) uint16

Comment: Ok, you have a colour image with 3 channels - Red, Green and Blue not the 1-channel greyscale image you shared. You can't really print a 3-channel image in a 2D Excel spreadsheet, so you'll either need to convert it to greyscale, or make a spreadsheet for the red channel and another for he green and another for the blue. Please tell me which you want.

Comment: Hi when I try to print it directly it shows [[1000 1000 1000]
  [ 995  995  995]
  [ 991  991  991]
  ...
  [ 994  994  994]
  [ 994  994  994]
  [ 994  994  994]]

Comment: Can you please tell me how to convert it to greyscale and print the pixels

Comment: You can use `greyImage = cv2.cvtColor(colourImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`