# Creating a table out of data in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am looking to create a table, with 4 columns.

In my program I have already formed a list with the information.
I can split the data into chunks of 4 (for each line), or make a separate list for every column.

Is it possible to create a table including these values inside the python program or would I need to export the data first?

EDIT: For Fauxpas

```
Column 1                Column 2                Column 3                Column 4            

              10                      10                      10                      30

              20                      10                      10                      40

              20                      20                      10                      50
```

Comment: What kind of table are you talking about? text, database, html?

Comment: Just one which could display numbers to a user which is easy to understand. 4 columns x 5 rows @Pedru

Comment: OK, you can either do it yourself like @Fauxpas suggetst or you can use some library like [texttable](https://github.com/foutaise/texttable/), there are many others.

Comment: This SO question might also be helpful to print pretty ascii-like tables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909873/python-pretty-printing-ascii-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to do this text based you could use the .format method, read the docs to learn about formatting so you can specify the spacing of each column

like

```
your_list = ['bread', 'milk', 'sugar', 'tea']

print("{0:20}    {1:20}    {2:20}    {3:20}\n".format('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4'))
print("{0:20}    {1:20}    {2:20}    {3:20}\n".format(your_list[0], your_list[1], your_list[2], your_list[3]))
```

Returns:

```
Column 1                Column 2                Column 3                Column 4            

bread                   milk                    sugar                   tea
```

With a for loop example getting closer to what you might be wanting to do:

```
your_list = ['bread', 'milk', 'sugar', 'tea', 'eggs', 'shampoo', 'clothes', 'tiger', 'beads', 'washing machine', 'juice', 'mixed herbs']

print("{0:20}    {1:20}    {2:20}    {3:20}\n".format('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4'))
i = 0
for x in range(0, 3):
    print("{0:20}    {1:20}    {2:20}    {3:20}\n".format(your_list[i], your_list[i + 1], your_list[i + 2], your_list[i + 3]))
    i += 4
```

Output:

```
Column 1                Column 2                Column 3                Column 4            

bread                   milk                    sugar                   tea                 

eggs                    shampoo                 clothes                 tiger               

beads                   washing machine         juice                   mixed herbs
```

EDIT:

```
your_list = ['10', 10, '20', 20]
print("{0:20}    {1:20}    {2:20}    {3:20}\n".format('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4'))
print("{0:20}    {1:20}    {2:20}    {3:20}\n".format(your_list[0], your_list[1], your_list[2], str(your_list[3])))
```

Output:

```
Column 1                Column 2                Column 3                Column 4            

10                                        10    20                      20
```

If you convert the integers in your list to Strings demonstrated by the last element in my format statement using the Str() method then this won't happen :)

```
str(your_list[3])
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: The columns won't align unless they have the exact same width.

Comment: Can you post your format statements? Make sure you put 4 spaces before the code and check the preview output.
Do this by editing your original post

Comment: @Fauxpas This works perfectly apart from the fact that the column titles and the data below them don't line up. Is there anyway to fix this? (Ive edited the original post)

Comment: I'm no expert but I think because you were passing integers, that they were becoming part of the formatting. Have added an edit for you.

Comment: Thanks this is so helpful works just how I wanted it to. Would you mind quickly explaining how the this works

Comment: This is the best article I could find to explain it https://mkaz.github.io/2012/10/10/python-string-format/