# How to print a number so it takes up exactly same space regardless of its number of digits?

Tags: python, string, numbers, format, digit

I have this

```
    Partition 0 | 0 | 0 | 4
    Partition 1 | 4 | 4 | 4
    Partition 2 | 8 | 8 | 8
    Partition 3 | 16 | 16 | 16
    Partition 4 | 32 | 32 | 32
```

I want to do this

```
Partition 0 |  0 |  0 |  4
Partition 1 |  4 |  4 |  4
Partition 2 |  8 |  8 |  8
Partition 3 | 16 | 16 | 16
Partition 4 | 32 | 32 | 32
```

Below is my Python 3 code, summarized. Where a,b,c,d are appropriate ints.

```
for i in range(5)
    print(("Partition %d | %d | %d | %d") % (a, b, c, d))
```

Basically, I want that space in between | | to be always the same,
no matter the digit.

Is there any way to achieve this simply using formatting perhaps?
I can think of achieving this using string formatting and adding/subtracting spaces depending on the number of digits but that sounds way too complicated.

I tried searching, but I'm stil learning so I don't know what terms I need to use to describe my problem. If you could refer to me to a relevant link to read that will be great as well.

Comment: you can find some options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909873/how-can-i-pretty-print-ascii-tables-with-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces this is something you're looking for

Comment: @ZPiDER   Thank you all!