# Format input dictionary string as columns

Tags: python

I am using the concat function to convert several database fields to be entered into a Tkinter Combobox.

```
Data:
first_name  last_name       city        state   ID
John        Smith           Dallas      TX      1
Richard     Cunningham      Ft. Worth   TX      2
'''
        SELECT concat (first_name,' ',last_name,' ', city,', ',state,' '),ID
'''
Results:
{'John Smith Dallas, TX':1, 'Richard Cunningham Ft. Worth, TX' :2 }
```

What I would like to do is format the string so that for example Smith would take the same number of characters as Cunningham. Then when I put the data into the cb it would appear as columns.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to create a table instead of a cb. A solution/ description for this is shown [Here (stackoverflow - does tkinter have a table widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348264/does-tkinter-have-a-table-widget).

Otherwise you could take advantage of libraries (or there logic) such as [texttable](https://github.com/foutaise/texttable) or [asciitable](https://cxc.cfa.harvard.edu/contrib/asciitable/) to format your text appropriately. A solution for general asciitable can be found [here - (stackoverflow - How can I pretty print ascii tables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909873/how-can-i-pretty-print-ascii-tables-with-python)